# Adding to a Generic Set passed into a method

Tags: java, generics, collections

Let us say I have the following classes:

- Animal
- Cat
- Dog
- Cow

Animal is the base class, cat, dog, and cow each subclass it.

I now have a `Set<Cat>`, `Set<Dog>` and `Set<Cow>` each of these are used in the same way, so it makes sense to make a generic function to operate on them:

```
private boolean addObject(Animal toAdd, Animal defVal, Set<? extends Animal> vals)
```

This works great, I can freely pass in my Sets with no problem.

The problem appears: I can't attempt to add the Animal toAdd to parameter vals. Googling reveals that if I change the method to read:

```
private boolean addObject(Animal toAdd, Animal defVal, Set<? super Animal> vals)
```

I will be able to add the Animal to parameter vals. This works, except now, I can't pass in my subclassed my Sets of Cats, Dogs, and Cows. Further research tells me that the following works, with no warnings to boot:

```
private <T> boolean addObject(T toAdd, T defVal, Set<? super T> vals)
```

The problem being, I need to be able to perform method calls that Animal's all have. This is easily gotten around using a simple cast:

```
((Animal)toAdd).getAnimalType()
```

Is there any way around this problem so I can keep the generic functionality, and not require casting? Aside from making my Sets all Sets of the Base Type, Animal in the case of this example?

Comment: *is there a way I can use <> without using an html code here?* => yes, see my edits. You rarely need to use html on SO.

Comment: +1 For your prior research. It's a rare thing on this site, sadly.

Comment: @assylias thanks for that. Now, if only I could remember that the next time I need to ask a question.

Comment: @DuncanJones I'm honestly quite lazy, so I generally try to solve the problem myself before going through the effort of asking the question.

Comment: @Legowaffles SO uses [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) for formatting.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Good research, you were almost there. You just need to add an upper bound to `T`.

```
private <T extends Animal> boolean addObject(T toAdd, T defVal, Set<? super T> vals)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. I'll mark it as the answer in 8 or so minutes when possible.

Comment: It might be useful to spell out what this method signature means. It means: "Given some type `T` which is either `Animal` or a subclass of `Animal` (like `Cat`), this method takes two arguments of type `T` plus a `Set` of either `T` (like `Set<Cat>`) or of some type that is a supertype of `T` (like `Set<Animal>`)." Omitting the `? super` from the `Set` argument would still allow this to work, just not with a `Set<Animal>`. But `Set<? extends Animal>` doesn't work, because `<? extends Animal>` means "some type that is either `Animal` or a subclass of `Animal` *but I don't know which subclass*."